# How to echo data from database grouped by a certain field then it will print them separate tables

Tags: php, mysql

here is my database i want them to be grouped in the field remarks:

[image]

Then it will echo them separately. different tables per remarks:

[this is the ouput that i want ithink its in a loop by i dont know how to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYrEB.png)

`

```
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_tracking group by remarks order by age asc ";

                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        $i=1;

                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id=$row['id'];
                $lname=$row['lname'];
                $fname=$row['fname'];
                $mname=$row['mname'];
                $add=$row['address'];
                $bday=date('F j, Y', strtotime($bday=$row['birthday']));
                $age=$row['age'];
                $cat=$row['remarks'];


                echo "<tr>
                    <td>$i</td>
                    <td>$fname</td>
                    <td>$mname</td>
                    <td>$lname</td>
                    <td>$add</td>
                    <td>$bday</td>
                    <td>$age</td>


                    "; 

                    ?>`
```

Comment: can you explain your expectation some more

Comment: i already edited the post sir..

Comment: @JRMartinez second solution in my anwer would give you the desired result. Or you can get all the records and render them differently in UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `ORDER` the records by `remarks` to group the records with same `remarks` together, e.g.:

```
SELECT fname, lanme, mname, address, birthday, age, remarks
FROM table
ORDER BY remarks;
```

Once done, you can write a logic in UI to render different tables based on `remark` value (e.g if next row has different `remark` than current row then render it into different table). This will be optimal and won't need lot of DB calls just for rendering purpose.

An alternative would be for you to use `GROUP BY` to get the different `remarks` and then loop over the result to get the records belonging to that remark (for different tables), e.g.:

```
SELECT remarks
FROM table
GROUP BY remarks;

SELECT fname, lanme, mname, address, birthday, age, remarks
FROM table
WHERE remarks = <remark>;
```

Comment: yes but  i want them to echo all in separate tables in a single page not only by a specific remarks

Comment: Yes, so you can use query 1 to get all the rows and write a logic in UI to create a separate table if you encounter different `remarks` than the last one. Or use 2 queries in solution 2 to render different tables.

Comment: can you help me with the code i dont get it .. i already updated my post with the code

Comment: Just declare a variable like `$previous_cat` and try comparing with `$row['remarks']`. If they are different, echo the header of a new table with `$row['remarks']`, if not, continue with current flow. That should do it.